# running arbitrary php files

Tags: php

I have a hostgator wordpress site. My friend wrote two small php scripts to help us with a medial task we do a lot in our work, but he is currently hosting this script on his server; I want to host it on our official server.

Is there a way to straight-up ftp this folder containing

1. two php files
2. a larger js file
3. a subfolder of multiple images

directly to my site and have it work? Every time I try to directly access the php file, wordpress automatically redirects to home (http://example.com). This is probably a very good security measure, but is there some way to whitelist these scripts to run without modifying them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress offers a dedicated API for your need: the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). So (let) write a plugin, which is really easy. Then you can use the extra code probably without conflicts.